# Check if a String satisfies a regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a List of String and I want to filter out the String that doesn't match a regex pattern

Input List = `Orthopedic,Orthopedic/Ortho,Length(in.)`

My code

```
for(String s : keyList){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9-_]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (!m.find()){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

I expect the 2nd and 3rd string to be printed as they do not match the regex. But it is not printing anything

Comment: Your pattern is "satisfied" if it matches just one character in the class. All your keys does that. I guess what you're after is something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$`

Comment: @ClasG Is there a method that would check for the entire string

Comment: Yes, `Matcher#matches`. Or, without compiling patterns: `String#matches`. Like `s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_]");`.

Comment: A comment on the `Pattern.compile()` placement. Place it before the loop. Using `Pattern.compile()` and then `Pattern.matcher(string)` can be a huge performance improvement over `String.matches()` if you need the same pattern multiple times, as you need the (expensive) `Pattern.compile()` only once and need to repeat only the (cheaper) `Pattern.matcher(string)` and `Matcher.matches()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

You are not matching the entire input. Instead, you are trying to find the next matching part in the input. From `Matcher#find`s [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--):

> Attempts to find the **next subsequence** of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

So your code will match an input if **at least one** character is one of `a-zA-Z0-9-_`.

---

### Solution

If you want to match the whole region you should use `Matcher#matches` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--)):

> Attempts to match the **entire region** against the pattern.

And you probably want to adjust your pattern to allow multiple characters, for example by a pattern like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+
```

The `+` allows `1` to infinite many repetitions of the pattern (`?` is `0` to `1` and `*` is `0` to infinite).

---

### Notes

You have an extra `-` at the end of your pattern. You probably want to remove that. Or, if you intended to match the character litteraly, you need to escape it:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]+
```

You can test your regex on sites like *regex101.com*, here's your pattern: [regex101.com/r/xvT8V0/1](https://regex101.com/r/xvT8V0/1).

Note that there is also `String#matches` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)). So you could write more compact code by just using `s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")`.

Also note that you can shortcut character sets like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` by using [predefined sets](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html). The set `\w` (word character) matches exactly your desired pattern.

Since the pattern and also the matcher don't change, you might want to move them outside of the loop to slightly increase performance.

---

### Code

All in all your code might then look like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

for (String s : keyList) {
    if (!m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Or compact:

```
for (String s : keyList) {
    if (!s.matches("\\w")) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Using streams:

```
keyList.stream()
    .filter(s -> !s.matches("\\w"))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't construct a `Pattern` in a loop, you currently only match a single character, and you can use `!String.matches(String)` and a `filter()` operation. Like,

```
List<String> keyList = Arrays.asList("Orthopedic", "Orthopedic/Ortho", "Length(in.)");
keyList.stream().filter(x -> !x.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+"))
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
Orthopedic/Ortho
Length(in.)
```

**Or**, using the `Pattern`, like

```
List<String> keyList = Arrays.asList("Orthopedic", "Orthopedic/Ortho", "Length(in.)");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+");
keyList.stream().filter(x -> !p.matcher(x).matches()).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:
1) the regular expression is wrong, it matches just one character.
2) you need to use `m.matches()` instead of `m.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matches` instead of `find`:

```
//Added the + at the end and removed the extra -
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+");

for(String s : keyList){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (!m.matches()){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Also note that the point of compiling a pattern is to reuse it, so put it outside the loop. Otherwise you may as well use:

```
for(String s : keyList){
    if (!s.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```